# Python input validation for integers greater than zero

Tags: python, validation, input

I have the following code that I'm trying to validate the input provided by the user to be greater than zero, but the value being returned is not the correct value - for instance, if I enter in a zero for the first angle and then type in something greater than zero, the zero is being returned and not the correct value.  Any ideas on how to fix?

```
def ValidTriangle(firstAngle, secondAngle, thirdAngle):

    if (firstAngle + secondAngle + thirdAngle) == 180:
        print("The triangle is indeed a valid triangle")
    else:
        print("The triangle is not valid")


def ValidateInput(angle):
        if angle <=0: 
            isValid = False
        else:
            isValid = True

        while isValid == False:
            try:
                angle = int(input('Please try again'))
                break

            except ValueError:
                return(angle)                

angle1 = int(input("Please enter the first angle of the triangle: \n"))
ValidateInput(angle1)
angle2 = int(input("Please enter the second angle of the triangle: \n"))
ValidateInput(angle2)
angle3 = int(input("Please enter the third angle of the triangle: \n"))
ValidateInput(angle3)

ValidTriangle(angle1,angle2,angle3)
```

Comment: `ValidateInput` only returns something when there is an error; not that it matters, since you don't do anything with any value returned.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure ValidateInput returns the modified angle. Also the while loop here can be replaced with recursion to call ValidateInput again:

```
def ValidTriangle(firstAngle, secondAngle, thirdAngle):

    if (firstAngle + secondAngle + thirdAngle) == 180:
        print("The triangle is indeed a valid triangle")
    else:
        print("The triangle is not valid")


def ValidateInput(prompt):
    angle = int(input(prompt))
    if angle <= 0:
        isValid = False
    else:
        isValid = True

    if not isValid:
        angle = ValidateInput('Please try again: ')

    return angle            

angle1 = ValidateInput("Please enter the first angle of the triangle: \n")
angle2 = ValidateInput("Please enter the second angle of the triangle: \n")
angle3 = ValidateInput("Please enter the third angle of the triangle: \n")

ValidTriangle(angle1,angle2,angle3)
```

Comment: _Also the while loop here can be replaced with recursion to call ValidateInput again_ Why...? Of all the changes that could be made....

Comment: Also this solution doesn't replicate the functionality of OP's program, since there is no checking whether or not the input is actually a valid int,

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put in a return angle clause under the condition IsValid is True and after breaking the while clause. You should add that and it should work. I.e.

```
def ValidateInput(angle):
    if angle <=0: 
        isValid = False
    else:
        isValid = True 
        return(angle)

    _angle = angle
    while isValid == False:
        try:
            _angle = int(input('Please try again'))
            break

        except ValueError:
            return(_angle)
```

You have it return on error, but also you have the variable being called into the function mimicking the one being made in the function, that's also confusing. It should return a different variable name to avoid that mimic too, I believe.

I may not have explained that well, but I hope that helps.

Comment: I still see the same result when I try it this way - i.e. only the invalid value is being returned

Comment: you need to store the returned value of ValidateInput into angle1 `angle1 = ValidateInput(angle1)` and so on with each of the ValidateInput calls. This way if ValidateInput got a new value for the angle, you are actually storing it and using it when you Validate the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not entirely certain what the best approach for accepting and validating input would be in this situation, this solution should be quite idiomatic and sensible.

```py
def is_valid_triangle(angle_1: float, angle_2: float, angle_3: float) -> bool:
    return angle_1 + angle_2 + angle_3 == 180


def get_gt_zero_input(prompt_msg: str) -> int:
    while True:
        raw_in = input(prompt_msg)
        try:
            int_val = int(raw_in)
        except ValueError:
            input(f'ERROR: Invalid input: {raw_in}.\nPress ENTER to continue.')
        else:
            if int_val > 0:
                return int_val
            else:
                input(f'ERROR: Input {int_val} is smaller than or equal to 0.\nPress ENTER to continue.')
```